# Linux Mint 15 refusing to boot after errorless install

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Installed Mint on a brand new Lenovo Z585 Ideapad alongside the pre-installed Windows 8. Everything seemed to go fine, until the reboot, which simply dumped me at a Grub prompt.

I tried the usual ls investigations, but my Mint partition (/dev/sda9) returns an error along the lines of "invalid file name ''." - sorry I can't be more precise right now.

I've booted back into the LiveCD and run boot-repair, which generated the following summary - http://paste2.org/Owy3XNpH.

os-prober recognises my Windows installs (the real install and the recovery thinger), but no Mint.

As far as I can see, browsing the partition through the live cd, the install itself is fine, but I'm more than willing to be corrected. Can anyone help?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the answer in case others have this problem.

Turns out that SecureBoot was in the Security section of the Bios, and not in the Boot section, where I was looking for it.

Disabling it and running boot-repair fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda

http://wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/install-the-grub-boot-loader-to-the-mbr